# About host : www.example.com , abc.www.example.com

Tags: dns, host, ngrok

When I deploy ngrok, I use a host like:www.example.com, in the client , I get this: 
To get started, make a request to one of your tunnel URLs:http://10f0df.www.example.com, 
This will lead a problem which can not find DNS address.
How can I fix this? TKS!

Answer (score 0):

Well,,,I get it! General analysis the domain!